# Should outliers in a time series be removed before or after detrending?

Tags: time-series, outliers, trend

I am doing a classical time series analysis. When do I remove outliers in the data?

After detrend or before detrend?

Comment: Outliers can influence the trend estimation, hence you have to remove them prior to the analysis.

Comment: It's a presumption here that you must remove outliers and a deeper presumption that you can identify them simply or at least objectively. But researchers often fail to agree on what is or is not an outlier, so the question is more complicated. An outlier is at most an outlier not only in relation to a dataset but also in relation to ideas about the data generating process. Many researchers prefer to accommodate apparent outliers to the maximum extent possible e.g. by working with a multiplicative model or by allowing extra terms in  a model to match unusual events.